# Multiple NSWindow hide on close and reopen when click on dock Icon

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa

I have an existing single window app. Now I want to make it multi-window-ready. I switched the window controller in storyboard from single window to multi window. And used this `applicationShouldHandleReopen` method:

```
func applicationShouldHandleReopen(_ sender: NSApplication, hasVisibleWindows flag: Bool) -> Bool {
            for window in sender.windows {
                if(window.windowController != nil && window.windowController?.contentViewController != nil && window.className != "NSStatusBarWindow") {
                    if(window.windowController?.contentViewController?.isKind(of: ViewController.self))! {
                        window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)
                    }
                }
            }
        return true
    }
```

Now I don't want to really close the open windows on click close, so I added this to my window controller:

```
func windowShouldClose(_ sender: NSWindow) -> Bool {
        sender.orderOut(self)
        return false
    }
```

But this works only on the initial window – the other windows get closed for real – so that clicking the dock icon only opens the inital window and not the new created windows.

Comment: Since it works for one window and not the other(s), what are the differences in implementation? Are they different kinds of windows? Are some set to 'release when closed' and others not? Is the 'visible at launch' key set for the first and not the others? Are the other windows set up as child-windows of the first?

Comment: The working window comes from storyboard and is the initial window (subclassed). The other windows are programmatically instantiated via Storyboard and the identifier. So it should be the same but it feels that delegate methods are not correctly working. Even if I explicit set delegate to self. Surprisingly the window looks correct so the subclass is also working here. I decided to create tabs in my own window and stay at single window. It’s even better for my app but to know why that happens would be nice.